# Laravel controller for creating payments with Mollie

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce

I have a controller with functions to create and finish a Mollie payment. But I've got the idea that those functions are too big and do too many things. What I understand is that a function should do only 1 thing.

Any tips on how I can tidy this further up? Is it maybe a good moment to use events? Or are there any better solutions?

Note: `creditBundles()` returns an array with possible packages/bundles which are currently for sale.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->payment = Mollie::api()->payments();
}

public function createPayment(Request $request, $bundle)
{
    $bundles = $this->creditBundles();

    if (!array_key_exists($bundle, $bundles)) {
        return redirect()->route('order.credits');
    }

    $order_id = time();
    $bundle = $bundles[$bundle];

    $payment = $this->payment->create([
        "amount"            => $bundle['price'],
        "description"       => $bundle['credits'] . " credits",
        "redirectUrl"       => route('order.credits.finish', ['order_id' => $order_id]),
        "webhookUrl"      => route('order.credits.webhook'),
        "metadata"          => ['order' => 'credits', 'order_id' => $order_id],
    ]);

    CreditOrder::create([
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        'order_id' => $order_id,
        'payment_id' => $payment->id,
        'payment_status' => $payment->status,
        'credits' => $bundle['credits'],
    ]);

    return redirect($payment->getPaymentUrl());
}

public function finish(CreditOrder $order)
{
    $user = auth()->user();

    if ($order->user_id !== $user->id) {
        return redirect()->route('order.credits');
    }

    $payment = $this->payment->get($order->payment_id);

    if (!$payment->isPaid() || $order->payout) {
        return view('order_status', [
            'payment' => $payment,
            'order' => $order,
        ]);
    }

    $user->increment('credits', $order->credits);
    $order->payout = true;
    $order->save();

    notify()->flash('Thanks ' . escape($user->first_name) . '!', 'success', [
        'text' => 'We received your payment and added ' . $order->credits . ' credits to your account!'
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the [Single Reponsibility Principle](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html) can [apply to methods](http://clean-swift.com/single-responsibility-principle-for-methods/) (I know that article is geared towards Swift but should hopefully still be practical in other languages).

While there are guidelines like [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/27802/244085):

> #### What's the Right Size, Really?
>
> Depends on the language you use, but in general (and for my personal taste):
>
> - **Ideally**, less than 25 lines.
> - **Acceptably**, less than 35 lines.

there are varying opinions. I try to keep methods under 10 lines if possible.

With the method *createPayment()*, the lines that handle creating the payment and CreditOrder could be moved out to a separate method:

```
/**
* Create a payment record and a CreditOrder
* @param $bundle
* @return Payment
*/
private function _createPaymentAndOrder($bundle) 
{
    $order_id = time();
    $payment = $this->payment->create([
        "amount"            => $bundle['price'],
        "description"       => $bundle['credits'] . " credits",
        "redirectUrl"       => route('order.credits.finish', ['order_id' => $order_id]),
        "webhookUrl"      => route('order.credits.webhook'),
        "metadata"          => ['order' => 'credits', 'order_id' => $order_id],
    ]);

    CreditOrder::create([
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        'order_id' => $order_id,
        'payment_id' => $payment->id,
        'payment_status' => $payment->status,
        'credits' => $bundle['credits'],
    ]);
    return $payment
}
```

Then those lines can be moved out and replaced with a call to that new method:

```
/**
* Attempt to create a payment record
* @param Request $request
* @param $bundle
*/
public function createPayment(Request $request, $bundle)
{
    $bundles = $this->creditBundles();

    if (!array_key_exists($bundle, $bundles)) {
        return redirect()->route('order.credits');
    }

    $bundle = $bundles[$bundle];
    $payment = $this->_createPaymentAndOrder($bundle);

    return redirect($payment->getPaymentUrl());
}
```

The names could be modified slightly so they aren't so close.

As far as the *finish()* method goes, the three lines below that actually update data could be moved into a separate method, unless that feels too small.

```
$user->increment('credits', $order->credits);
$order->payout = true;
$order->save();
```

And one could move the first couple blocks that check that the user is the same as the user on the order and the payment is paid into a separate method to handle error checking. If that method returned a certain value (e.g. `true` to signify an error occurred, `false` that no error occurred) then the rest of the method could be run accordingly.